# I had the following conjecture in combinatorics, regarding seating arrangement

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $n, m $ be odd integers of the form $5 +4k$, $k=0,1,2,$. If we have a table, seating $n*m$ guests, so that every guest knows exactly half of the other guests at their table, then we can split the table up in $n$ tables, each seating $m$ guests, so that every guest knows exactly half of other guests at their table.

Intuitively, I'm pretty confident that this conjecture is correct, but I have no idea how to prove it. Any thoughts, tips, or counterexamples are appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: At first glance, this seems to me to be a tough nut to crack.  However, I imagine that for other MathSE reviewers, it is probably routine, assuming that the assertion is true.  Anyway, if I was attacking the problem, and the source of the problem is a book or class, my first try would be to review the theorems, worked examples, or solved problems (i.e. **the tools**) that led up to this problem.  That is, I would presume that the educational motivation behind this problem is to practice using the tools to solve the problem.  ...see next comment

Comment: So, I would then very carefully review the tools, be they Combinatorics, Graph Theory, some other version of Number Theory, or whatever.

Comment: We cannot seat 7 guests at a table, because then total number of edges is $\frac{7\cdot 3}{2}=\frac{21}{2}$. But I don't see why we cannot seat 49 guests at a table.

Comment: Ah then $n, m$ should be of the form $5 + 4k$, right?

Answer (score 0):

This conjecture is incorrect and have a counterexample.

The problem can be restated in words of graph theory, like following:

> Given a $\frac{nm-1}{2}$-regular graph $G = (V, E)$ such that $|V| = nm$, we can split $V$ into $n$ groups $\{V_1, V_2, \dots, V_n\}$, such that for each $i$, $|V_i| = m$ and the graph induced by $V_i$ is a $\frac{m-1}{2}$-regular graph.

As a preparation, we can assume $(n, m) = (4k+1, 4l+1)$ or $(n, m) = (4k+3, 4l+3)$ for some $k, l$. Otherwise $nm \equiv 3 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 4)$ therefore $nm$ and $\frac{nm-1}{2}$ will be odd; there's no such regular graph.

Now we construct the counterexample graph. Let $V = \{0, 1, 2, \dots, nm-2, nm-1\}$. For $0 \leq x \lt y \leq nm-1$, we draw edges by the following conditions:

- Case of $y \neq nm-1$: Draw edge $xy$ if and only if $x \not\equiv y \ (\mathrm{mod} \  2)$ and $(x, y) \neq (4k, 4k+1)$ for all $k$.
- Case of $y = nm-1$: Draw edge $xy$ if and only if $x \equiv 0, 1 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 4)$.

We can easily see that the constructed graph is $\frac{nm-1}{2}$-regular. And also, if we erase the vertex $nm-1$, the graph will be bipartite, because this part is purely constructed by parity.

However, if a induced subgraph is bipartite, it cannot be a $\frac{m-1}{2}$-regular graph. Let the partition of bipartite subgraph be $\{U_1, U_2\}$. We must hold (degree sum in $U_1$) = (degree sum in $U_2$) due to bipartiteness. However, since $m = |U_1| + |U_2|$ is odd, it is sure that $|U_1| \neq |U_2|$, so the aim of "all degrees are equal" cannot be achieved.

Since only one group can use vertex $nm$, the other $n-1$ groups will be bipartite. Such groups cannot be $\frac{m-1}{2}$-regular as said previously. So, this case is the counterexample of the conjecture.

Comment: I noticed that the question was changed for $n, m$ to be limited in $4k + 1$ form... However, this proof is based on "$n, m$ is odd", so please note that it doesn't cause a problem in the proof.

Comment: Yeah I realized there can't be tables where everyone knows half, of size 7, 11, 15 etc,  sorry for that. I'll study your proof now

Comment: Okay I see what you do, you start with some problematic arrangement of the m*n table, and then conclude you can't split them up. But why wouldn't there  be some other n*m arrangement? It's a bit annoying that n*m is too large to draw. But you made your problematic arrangement, how can you be sure that I can't rearrange the same guests in an arrangement where I can split them?   Do you claim that for all n and 'm,  it is never possible?

Comment: @AndroidBeginner To be clear, for all $(n, m)$, there exists such a problematic case (of friendship relations) that guests of "not knowing half" exists for all possible ways of group splitting.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try to research it a bit deeper. I  Given some table of size  n= 4k +1, how many truly different cases are there? For which n could you always seat someone between two strangers?